# Автообновление блока с новостями

Tags: ajax

Есть блок с лентой последних новостей. Как замутить автообновление новостей? Т.е. пользователь находится на сайте, читает новость. В этот момент админ добавляет новую новость на сайт, а в блоке с лентой новостей со звуковым сопровождением появляется та самая новая новость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Здравствуйте.*

Данную задачу можно выполнив очень просто, нам нужен скрипт **php** на проверку новостей, а также скрипт **jQuery** для отправки запроса на проверку.

**php:**

*Создадим файлик news.php*

```
<?php
$zap = $_POST['zap']; //Переменная для запроса

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo "Автор: ".$row['avtor']."<br>
        Новость: ".$row['text']."<br>";
}
?>
```

*В данном скрипте мы выводим все новости.*

**jQuery:**

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post('news.php',{zap:'zap'},function(data){
    if(data){
      $('#news').text(data);
    }
  });
},10000);
```

*В этом скрипте мы кидаем запрос каждые 10 секунд на проверку новостей, при этому новости мы выводим в* `<div id='news'></div>`

А звуковое сопровождение уже найдите [**Здесь**](http://google.com)

Comment: Спасибо, друг!

Comment: @vinnie, всегда пожалуйста.